# How can i make text change color when i cliked in my cell

Tags: angularjs

I want to change the colors of my cell, so in my table i do this on my `td`

```
data-ng-class="{selected: selected.id == price.id && price.isMinPrice}"
```

> if is selected and is a min price i want have a colors

but this code line do nothing, why ?

Comment: you should try to put up a simple plunker to verify your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

Here you can define any conditional in a ternary operator

```
data-ng-class="selected.id == price.id && price.isMinPrice ? 'selected-class' : ''"
```

You can also add more classes for both cases like this:

```
data-ng-class="some-condition ? 'selected-class' : 'no-selected-class another-class'"
```

Full example:

```js
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test').controller('controll', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
      value: 1,
      selected: false
    }, {
      value: 2,
      selected: true
    }, {
      value: 3,
      selected: false
    }]

  }
]);
```

```css
.selected-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="test">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-controller="controll">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td data-ng-class="item.selected ? 'selected-class' : ''">{{item.value}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```